# Repeated measure anova in R

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, anova

I want to run a 2 way repeated measure anova in R to examine the effects of grop and phase variables on the res variables. This is my data.

```
res=round(runif(48,min = 0 ,max=44))
grop=factor(c(rep(1,16) , rep(2,16) , rep(3,16)))
id=factor(rep(gl(24,2),1))
phase=factor(rep(gl(2,1),24))
```

where id is the subject that have 24 levels and grop and phase are fixed factors with 2 levels each. In repeated measures anova ,id is a random factor.

So first, I tried to fit the mixed effects anova using the expected mean square technique. so to get expected mean squares , i got the anova table as follows,
(Here I don’t want to test the interaction between the id and treatments)

```
modlm=lm(res~ id +  grop*phase)
anova(modlm)
```

[image]

So here grop is not included in the model: that may due to the estimability problems.

If I fit the same model using lmer in R, I get the following results:

```
library("lme4", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.5")
modelrat=lmer(res~ (1|id) +  grop*phase)
anova(modelrat)
ranova(modelrat)
```

[image]

So here the effect of grop is also estimated.

So I want to know why is there a difference between the outputs. I think I should get the same answer using lm function by using the expected mean squares. Is there anything wrong in the model that I am going to test?

Can anyone help to figure that out?

Comment: By thinking about this model , i just thought that testing for main effects is not appropriate in this case. is it correct ?

Answer (score 2):

The results ***should*** be different because they come from two different models.

What's surprising is how similar they are for some terms.  I suppose this is because --- looking at the `ranova(modelrat)` output --- `id` has almost no discernible effect.

I don't know what example you are following for "*the mixed effects anova using the expected mean square technique*", but the `lm` model you used does not match the description of what you say you are trying to achieve. It's not a mixed-effects model, and `id` isn't treated as a random factor.  It's not a great model for the repeated measures situation you mention.

In R, there is a way to make a more appropriate model for nested effects, using `lm` and then `aov` where you specify the error term to use for hypothesis tests.

But honestly, you are probably better off using `lmer` or `nlme` to fit mixed-effects models that are appropriate for your purposes.